# Cannot find embedded resource assembly named Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Resources.Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, yui-compressor, antiforgerytoken

I am using throughout my NopCommerce website a component called BundleTransformer which extends the 'bundling' feature of MVC4. It uses another component called Yahoo.Yui.Compressing to transform and compress javascript files. All is working fine. JS files are compressed and bundled as expected.

However, there seems to be an issue with AntiForgeryToken. In my registration page, I added this simple line inside my form:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This seems to conflict with Yahoo.Yui.Compressing. The error message I am getting is here below:

```
Cannot find embedded resource assembly named Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Resources.Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Cannot find embedded resource assembly named Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Resources.Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

Source Error: 


Line 43: @using (Html.BeginForm())
Line 44: {
Line 45:     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
Line 46:     <div class="page registration-page">
Line 47:         <div class="page-body">

Source File: e:\www\....\TheWebsite\Themes\TheTheme\Views\Customer\Register.cshtml    Line: 45 

Stack Trace: 


[DllNotFoundException: Cannot find embedded resource assembly named Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Resources.Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll]
   Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.AssemblyResolver.<Initialise>b__0(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) +248
   System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName) +224

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Could not find the specified DllImport Dll.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +50
   System.Web.Helpers.Claims.ClaimsIdentityConverter.GetDefaultConverters() +71
   System.Web.Helpers.Claims.ClaimsIdentityConverter..cctor() +91

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Helpers.Claims.ClaimsIdentityConverter' threw an exception.]
   System.Web.Helpers.Claims.ClaimsIdentityConverter.get_Default() +14
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.CreateSingletonAntiForgeryWorker() +124
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery..cctor() +8

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery' threw an exception.]
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() +45
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken() +21
   ASP._Page_Themes_CambridgeSatchel_Views_Customer_Register_cshtml.Execute() in e:\www\....\TheWebsite\Themes\TheTheme\Views\Customer\Register.cshtml:45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +236
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Does anyone know the solution?

It seems to be a bug somewhere between Yahoo.Yui.Compressor, BundleTransformer or the AntiForgeryToken.

Comment: can you find `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Resources.Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll` on your system anywhere? If yes, what happens if copy it to the same folder as mscorlib ?

Comment: No. It doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: isn't that the problem? find that file or re-install whatever ships it and you're good to go?

Comment: No. That's not the problem. It seems to be looking for a dll file that doesn't exist. It seems to be a bug somewhere between Yahoo.Yui.Compressor, BundleTransformer or the AntiForgeryToken.

Comment: are you saying that dll is not required?

Comment: if you believe that to be true, then compile your own .net assembly and give it the same name. it must be used somewhere tho as something is trying to load a class in that assembly using `GetType`

Comment: in your web.config, what minifier is set to default minifier: <js defaultMinifier="...." usePreMinifiedFiles="true">  ... is it yahoo minifier?

Comment: and which version of BundleTransformer are you using?

Comment: Hi Kabaros, I was using the version 1.6.5 which was released only a few weeks ago. I have just updated it to the latest one 1.6.6 and it fixed the problem.  Make a post, and i will award you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to BundleTransformer 1.6.6 solves the problem.

There was a problem with BundleTransformer 1.6.5 and YUI Compressor .NET 2.1.0.0 that was fixed in the last release (See Taritsyn comment on http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/discussions/398013/)